# How can i Send Sms From Firebase using unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

Have a Nice Day...I am learning Firebase. In my app how can i send sms (Password Verfication Code).From Unity.

Could any one help me.

Comment: is your app on mobile and if yes it is for Android or IOS or both ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Firebase documentation for Unity on sending a SMS verification code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone):

> Call `PhoneAuthProvider.VerifyPhoneNumber`, passing to it the user's phone number.
>
> ```
> PhoneAuthProvider provider = PhoneAuthProvider.GetInstance(firebaseAuth);
> provider.VerifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, phoneAuthTimeoutMs, null,
>   verificationCompleted: (credential) => {
>     // Auto-sms-retrieval or instant validation has succeeded (Android only).
>     // There is no need to input the verification code.
>     // `credential` can be used instead of calling GetCredential().
>   },
>   verificationFailed: (error) => {
>     // The verification code was not sent.
>     // `error` contains a human readable explanation of the problem.
>   },
>   codeSent: (id, token) => {
>     // Verification code was successfully sent via SMS.
>     // `id` contains the verification id that will need to passed in with
>     // the code from the user when calling GetCredential().
>     // `token` can be used if the user requests the code be sent again, to
>     // tie the two requests together.
>   },
>   codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (id) => {
>     // Called when the auto-sms-retrieval has timed out, based on the given
>     // timeout parameter.
>     // `id` contains the verification id of the request that timed out.
>   });
> ```

See the linked documentation for full information.

Comment: Thanks Frant For Your code. I have used ur code. But Sms is not received. I have enabled phone authentication.What i have to do for receiving sms.

For others user . if your post above code. you will receive error. So Change this 
codeAutoRetrievalTimeout

to codeAutoRetrievalTimeOut  

for to solve the error.

Comment: While searching Forum  i have found SHA Certificate Fingerprint to enabled.Shall i have to enable to send sms .

Comment: I am doing only testing. I am using unity 2018. and paste the above code and added google-services. but sms is not recieved. More than what i have to do?